# Array Push method inside loop not displaying expected results

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have 2 dates.  `Date1 = "1/1/2022"` and `Date2 = "1/3/2022"`.  I want to create an array consisting of `["1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022"]`.  Quite straightforward.  Not sure why my code is not working.  Attached is screenshot image of my code after it runs.  The array result it's giving me is `["1/4/2022", "1/4/2022", "1/4/2022"]`.

[image: code and console.log]

```js
function test1() {
    var array = []
    var date1 = new Date(2022, 0, 1)
    var date2 = new Date(2022, 0, 3)
    d = date1
    while (d <= date2) {
        console.log(d)
        array.push(d)
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
    }

    console.log(array)
}

test1();
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add code and logs as text not as image.

Answer (score 1):

you are updating the same reference, which is changing values already stored in array.

try this:

```
while(d <= date2) {
   array.push(d)
   var copy = new Date()
   copy.setTime(d.getTime())
   copy.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
   d = copy
}
```

this will ensure that `d` is a new object in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  function test1() {
    var array = [];
    var date1 = new Date(2022, 0, 1);
    var date2 = new Date(2022, 0, 3);
    d = date1;
    while (d.valueOf() <= date2.valueOf()) {
        console.log(d);
        array.push(new Date(d));
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
    }
  console.log(array)    
  }

Execution log
5:49:29 PM  Notice  Execution started
5:49:29 PM  Info    Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
5:49:29 PM  Info    Sun Jan 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
5:49:29 PM  Info    Mon Jan 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
5:49:29 PM  Info    [ Sat Jan 01 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  Sun Jan 02 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time),
  Mon Jan 03 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) ]
5:49:30 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you.  My mistake was I did not use "new Date(d)" as argument in my push function.  I just used d.  My error created weird results.